# How to disable Vuetify carousel jump to carousel on cycling?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In a Vue 2 SPA I use Vuetify. On the home page I have a carousel that auto cycles through 3 v-carousel-items. For the first cycle of the v-carousel the viewport jumps to the carousel on cycling. The desired behaviour is for the carousel to continue cycling but not to pull the viewport. Weirdly it happens in Chrome but not in Firefox. I found a similiar problem adressed in https://www.programmersought.com/article/15814769396/.

```
<v-carousel 
      progress 
      :progress-color="secondColorComputed" 
      interval=7000 
      cycle 
      height="750px" 
      class="mx-auto ; my-4 ;" 
      show-arrows-on-hover>

      <v-carousel-item 
        transition="false"
        reverse-transition="false">
        <v-card width="90%" class="mx-auto ; black--text" shaped :color="colorComputed">
          <v-card-title>Sub Seasonal Outlook</v-card-title>
          <!-- <v-container fluid> -->
            <v-row align="center" justify="center">
              <v-card width="50%">
                <v-img
                  alt="GIF 1"
                  class="shrink"
                  contain
                  src="https://hpfx.collab.science.gc.ca/~svfs000/na-vfsp-was/public/assets/geps/ss-precip.png"
                  width="800"/>
              </v-card>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-card width="50%">
                <v-img
                  alt="GIF 2"
                  class="shrink"
                  contain
                  src="https://hpfx.collab.science.gc.ca/~svfs000/na-vfsp-was/public/assets/geps/ss-temp.png"
                  width="800"/>
              </v-card>
            </v-row>
          <!-- </v-container> -->
          <v-btn :color="secondColorComputed" to="/forecasts/sub-seasonal-outlook">More</v-btn>
        </v-card>
      </v-carousel-item>

      <v-carousel-item 
        transition="false"
        reverse-transition="false">
        <v-card width="90%" class="mx-auto ; black--text" shaped :color="colorComputed">
          <v-card-title>Multi Model Ensemble 03H Continental USA</v-card-title>
          <!-- <v-container fluid> -->
            <v-row align="center" justify="center">
              <v-spacer/>
              <v-card width="75%">
                <v-img
                  alt="GIF 1"
                  class="shrink"
                  contain
                  src="https://hpfx.collab.science.gc.ca/~svfs000/na-vfsp-was/public/assets/mme-pm25-combined/conUS-pm25-03.png"
                  />
              </v-card>
              <v-spacer/>
            </v-row>
          <!-- </v-container> -->
          <v-btn :color="secondColorComputed" to="/forecasts/multi-model-ensemble">More</v-btn>
        </v-card>
      </v-carousel-item>

      <v-carousel-item 
        transition="false"
        reverse-transition="false">
        <v-card width="90%" class="mx-auto ; black--text" shaped :color="colorComputed">
          <v-card-title>Fire Weather Index 24H</v-card-title>
          <!-- <v-container fluid> -->
            <v-row align="center" justify="center">
              <v-spacer/>
              <v-card width="50%">
                <v-img
                  alt="GIF 1"
                  class="shrink mr-2"
                  contain
                  src="https://hpfx.collab.science.gc.ca/~svfs000/na-vfsp-was/public/assets/fwi/fwi-24.png"
                  width="800"/>
              </v-card>
              <v-spacer/>
            </v-row>
          <!-- </v-container> -->
          <v-btn :color="secondColorComputed" to="/forecasts/fire-weather-index">More</v-btn>
        </v-card>
      </v-carousel-item>

    </v-carousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine issue got resolved by replacing *transition* to *fade* transition.

```
 <v-carousel :cycle="true" interval="3000">
<v-carousel-item
  v-for="(item,i) in items"
  :key="i"
  :src="item.src"
  fade    
></v-carousel-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly the same issue as what you're having, but I had a problem with the page jumping up to the carousel on slide change, and managed to get it to stop doing this by setting the wrapper to have no height. (I'm using the fade animations.)

```
.v-window__container {
 height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gemma I am afraid this did not work but if you know why it should work, can you please explain it so I can perhaps adapt your solution to my case?